# Как с OnMouseOver над img document'а получить (SRC) URI этого изображения?

Tags: javascript

Не могу сообразить, каким образом с помощью события OnMouseOver наведением указателя мыши над любым изображением documenta прочитать(получить) (SCR)URI этого изображения и этот URL присвоить переменной. Ну а дальше я уже как то сам. Если можно помогите с таким javascript кодом.

Answer (score 3):

```
<img id="ShowMeYourSRC:)" src="/img/someImg.jpg"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("ShowMeYourSRC:)").onmouseover = function() {
         alert(this.src)
    }
}
</script>
```

**UPD**

Если за пределами видимости, то, например как-то вот так вот

```
onload = function() {
    alert("src картинки - " + document.getElementById("ShowMeYourSRC:)").src)
}
```

Т.е. чтобы, например, записать src картинки с id "ShowMeYourSRC:)" в переменную

```
onload = function(){
      var src = document.getElementById("ShowMeYourSRC:)").src;
      alert(src);
}
```

PS: дабы не терятся в базах языка советую вам прочесть [эту книгу](http://javascript.ru/book/definitiveguide)

Comment: Хотя я не до конца сформулировал вопрос Вы предложили наиболее удачный, и главное, работающий код

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ нажмите галочку сверху чуть левее вопроса :)

Comment: Ваш скрипт оказался подходящим, работающим, однако я, неожиданно столкнулся с проблемой передачи значения переменной, и сколько не горбатился не смог её переопределить с целью сохранения значения и передачи в другой скрипт, который выставляет новое изображение при наведении на изображение Собственно говоря, переменная объявленная и определённая как this.src уже за пределами области предложенной Вами функции теряет своё значение. Сдаюсь, не могу осуществить её передачу. А вообще это возможно?
Уже пробовал тот скрипт вложить в тело предложенной Вами в скрипте функции, всё равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="..." onmouseover="x=this.src;" >
```

В переменной `x` сохранится адрес имиджа

Answer (score 0):

Это неправильно правильно так:

html:

```
<img onmouseout="onmouseimgoverorout(event)">
```

и для других событий тоже используйте

```
`onmouseimgoverorout(event)`
```

javascript:

```
function onmouseimgoverorout(evt){ 
var evet;
var imgobj;
if(window.event){
evet=window.event.type; 
imgobj=window.event.srcElement;
}
else{
evet=evt.type;
imgobj=evt.target;
}
if(evet=="mouseover"){
//Когда mouseover
}
if(evet=="mouseout"){
// Когда mouseout
}
//imgobj это ваша картинка
}
```

Comment: Это по вашему правильно? xD

Comment: точно что xD) катать целую функу дабы узнать src изображения)

Comment: Раз уж дошло до создания такой функции, еще бы расписали, как правильно навесить событие, а то `onmouseout="onmouseimgoverorout(event)"` как-то некошерно.